# PL/SQL script probably fails on memory in a serie of loops

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm running a PL/SQL script that parses XML file. This file is really BIG one and it contains information about tens thousands subjects. For each subject there is few basic information and link to another XML file with details for specific subject. I'm parsing this file and saving data into database table. I'm pretty sure, that parser is fine and error is not on the side of parser.
I don't need to store details of all subjects, only about approximately 6 000 of them. Here's procedure of how i do it:

```
DECLARE 
  v_url VARCHAR2(200);
  x XMLType;
  y XMLType;
  detaily_url VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  v_url  := 'http://seznam.gov.cz/ovm/datafile.do?format=xml'||chr(38)||'service=seznamovm';
  x := get_xml_by_url(v_url);  %function that returns XML with details as XMLType object

  FOR kod IN (
  SELECT ... %Statement that returns list of codes of subjects that I want to work with
  ) LOOP
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT ExtractValue(Value(p),'/Subjekt/DetailSubjektu/text()') as url 
    FROM TABLE (XMLSequence(Extract(x,'SeznamOvmIndex/Subjekt'))) p
    WHERE ExtractValue(Value(p),'/Subjekt/Zkratka/text()') = kod.zkratka
    )  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(kod.zkratka);
    y := get_xml_by_url(r.url);
    FOR s IN (
      SELECT ExtractValue(Value(q),'/DetailSubjektu/AdresaUradu/AdresniBod/text()') as adresa_adresniBod
           ... % extracting more values 
          ,ExtractValue(Value(q),'/DetailSubjektu/Nazev/text()') as nazev
      FROM TABLE (XMLSequence(Extract(y,'DetailSubjektu'))) q
      )
      LOOP
        INSERT ... INTO TABLE VALUES ...;
        COMMIT;

      END LOOP;  
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line('Pocet obci: '||i);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Some parts of code are shortened, because it's not relevant for this problem. I'm sure, that this code works for the small  number of subjects in kod variable and I have successfully tested it on few hundreds of records.
My problem is that when I run it for 6 000 records, script throws an error in which it complains about XML it's reading. But thats nonsense. When I run the script for a smaller queue of subjects including the one which failed last time, it runs without problems.
I suppose that problem must be with a huge amount of data and I think that memory of SQL Developer is overloaded. But I don't know how to free it during the running of script. Could anyone help me?

Comment: What is the exact Oracle exception (ORA-....) ? What does make yoy thinking this is SQL Developer isue ? Did you try this in SQL*Plus ?

Comment: ORA-31011
ORA-19202
LPX-00249

I don't think it's SQL Developer issue, I suppose it's memory issue

Comment: if Oracle is complaining about invalid XML chars, I don't think you should ignore it and assume its nonsense.  Perhaps you can add a translate when you extract xml to translate these chars to a space.  At the very least, you could catch these in a sub block and log them, at least you could move on in the loop.

Comment: XML functions like *ExtractValue* require that entire XML File is loaded into memory, it's called DOM parser (document object model). There you have quite a big overhead, 10-50 times the size of XML File may occur. If your XML-Files is bigger than let's say "upper two-digit MByte" you should better use an event based parser - unless you have really huge server with a lot of memory and CPU power.

Comment: The big XML has 8 MB, XML files with details has only about 8kB. Problem is that there's a lot of them. But I'm not sure if they don't remain in a memory somehow (they should not). 
I don't have really huge server. Could you give me an advice on an "event based parser"?

Comment: tbone: Oracle is comlaining on invalid XML chars. So I checked the file on which it failed and ran the script again for that file. I got no error. Therefore I think that error is somewhere else.

Comment: if your invalid XML char exceptions are really due to lack of memory (I doubt it, but stranger things have happened), then using a sub block and catching exceptions (logging and skipping those that fail) will either skip some records, or if you're correct, will start throwing this exception on every row once the memory wall is hit.  Either way you'd know more whats going on.  Just a thought, easy enough to wrap the inner loops in begin exception end block

Comment: Including exceptions actually almost solved my problem. Among  all 6~253 files, there was only 6 errors, 5 of them while reading XML files and one while writing into database. The rest is OK, so now I'm focusing on those 6 invalid files...